# What is a single word for a jack of all trades?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who is a jack of all trades; he has done almost everything, knows everything, has gone everywhere, and is quite experienced.

Is there any single word for such a person?

Comment: That kind of person is likely to be a bore.

Comment: The Most Interesting Man in the World. That is, what @centaurus said.

Answer (score 2):

**Renaissance man:** *(n.)* a man with many talents or areas of knowledge
**Factotum:** *(n.)* a handyman who does all kinds of work
**Tinker:** *(n.)* a person skilled at various minor tasks
**Mr. Fixit:** *(n.)* *colloq* for tinker
**Pantologist:** *(n.)* a person who has a a systematic view of all human knowledge
**Globetrotter** *(n.)* a person who travels regularly or frequently

Different words to describe each trait. I guess Renaissance man is the most befitting your description.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Comment: Hey Jimmy, welcome to ELU. While your terms & definitions are certainly apt responses to this OP, they yet lack source citations (in plain, rather than hypertext). Please edit in (don't use a sharpie, it'll mess up your monitor screen) so I can up-vote this answer.  ;-)

Comment: It seems like you cited from different sources, if  they all came from a single source you could write: "Source: Oxford Dictionaries" at the end and be done with it. You really should cite where you took these definitions from, adding a direct link is helper friendly but not essential.

Answer (score 2):

Polymath (renaissance man), handyman, ...

Comment: On second thought... this doesn't address the "gone everywhere" thing.  Well traveled and knowledgeable.... hum.  Globe trotting polymath?

Answer (score 1):

You could say he's ***cosmopolitan***, ***worldly***, or a real ***man about town.***

[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/worldly) gives this definition of *worldly*:

> You can use the adjective worldly to describe **people who have knowledge of many topics or experience in many areas**.
>
> You don't have to travel the globe to be worldly; **reading and talking about many things with knowledge** and enthusiasm is worldly too.
>
> Worldly often describes individuals who are **sophisticated and well-rounded** in education, travel, and experiences.

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cosmopolitan) gives the definition of the adjective *cosmopolitan* as:

> So sophisticated as to be at home in all parts of the world or **conversant with many spheres of interest**: a cosmopolitan traveler.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=man%20about%20town) (AHD) defines *man about town* as:

> A sophisticated, socially active man who frequents fashionable places.

The common thread among all these words is that the person has either literally or figuratively traveled so much that he's exposed himself to many ideas and experiences (*cosmopolitan* is, in its original Greek, literally "*a person of the world*", as opposed to a specific place).

Comment: First time I've heard a *Jack of all trades' described as a 'man about town'! Perhaps we are dealing in too many metaphors.

Comment: @WS2: I think maybe Dan was taking the expression in the question as written: *jack of all trends*, instead of assuming the OP meant *jack of all trades*.

Comment: @WS2 I focused more on the "been everywhere, done everything, knows a lot, is quite experienced" aspects of the OP, as opposed to the "jack of all trades part". I think my answer is quite apt for a person with those characteristics.

Answer (score -1):

> [**sciolist**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sciolist)
>    *One who exhibits only superficial knowledge; a self-proclaimed expert with little real understanding.*
>   **2003**, Roy Porter, Flesh in the Age of Reason (Penguin), p. 290:
>   *Walter is [...] a dupe to the half-baked speculations of every **sciolist** from Descartes down to ‘Coglionissimo Borri’, and a pack of other dunces.*
>   **1893**, James McNeill Whistler, "The Decadent Movement in Literature" (Harper's Magazine): *But M. Dujardin is a poet; "vers libres" in the hands of a **sciolist** are the most intolerably easy and annoying of poetical exercises.*

source:Wiktionary

Answer (score -1):

**[multipotentialite](http://puttylike.com/terminology/)**

> My Definition.
>   A *multipotentialite* is a person who has many different interests and creative pursuits in life. Multipotentialites have no “one true calling” the way specialists do. Being a multipotentialite is our destiny.
>
> “An educational and psychological term referring to a pattern found among intellectually gifted individuals. [Multipotentialites] generally have diverse interests across numerous domains and may be capable of success in many endeavors or professions, they are confronted with unique decisions as a result of these choices.”
>
> <sup>Source: Puttylike.com</sup>

I myself am a Multipotentialite. I stumbled upon this apropos term recently while on a quest for my own personal compass. Multipotentialites are also interchangeably referred to as:

• Polymath / Renaissance Person
• Scanner
• Slasher
• Generalist
• Multipassionate
• RP2
• Puttylike Personality, Puttypeep
• Multipod
• Plate Spinner