# "Jack of all trades" or similar word that begins with 'M' with as few syllables as possible?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm hoping some more educated people can help come up with words that show a variety of skill sets, such as "Jack of all Trades" but with a word that begins with "M" and with as little syllables as possible.

A creative example would be something like "Multicore" where it represents several different things and could be interpreted as as many different skill sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108536/what-is-a-synonym-for-jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none/178586 or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253749/what-is-a-single-word-for-a-jack-of-all-trades or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239768/synonyms-for-renaissance-man or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/what-is-another-word-for-all-round-capabilities

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for people to coin new words. An established word close to what you're looking for in meaning, but not in starting letter, is *polymath*.

Comment: A Mary of many Masteries.

Comment: "Maven" is someone unusually knowledgeable in one field.  "Multi-Maven" or "mass-maven" could be an odd constructs if you're looking for a shorthand to use within a context.  Those made-up words wouldn't mean much on their own until you spelled out the concept to your audience.

Comment: Multi-talented, multifaceted..  Although not that short.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the simplistic multitasker?  Or, how about multiminded?

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer. It could be a comment. We are looking for detailed and well researched answers. This can be a challenge if the question is poorly stated.

Comment: Was the question poorly stated in this case?